# Make a Successive form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I want to make successive form with Symfony 2.7 (2 forms) but I can not. The second form uses data from the first.

I tried this :

```
   if($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
        $lot = new Lot();
        if($request->request->has('logiciel_version_debut_form')) {
            /*
                SEND FIRST VALUE FORM
            */
            $lot->setDateDebut(new \DateTime($request->get('logiciel_version_debut_form')['date_debut']['year'] . '-' . $request->get('logiciel_version_debut_form')['date_debut']['month'] . '-' . $request->get('logiciel_version_debut_form')['date_debut']['day']));
        }
        /*
            SECOND FORM FORM
        */
        $form = $this->createForm('logiciel_lot_form', $lot);
        $this->submit($form);
        if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
            /*
                OK GOOD :-)
            */
        }
    } else {
        /*
            FIRST FORM
        */
        $form = $this->createForm('logiciel_version_debut_form');
        $this->submit($form);
    }
    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'title' => 'Ajouter un nouveau lot'
    );
```

But it does not test if the first is valid. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't doing what you want with autobinding handleRequest() in the same level request.

Comment: Thanks, How then do ? :/

Comment: You have to create one form that contains the both subforms 'logiciel_lot_form' and 'logiciel_version_debut_form'

Comment: I don't want create two nested form, because the second form take date of first form, and force that.

Comment: Why you can't save date in the parent from ?
Anyway you can access the date of the first form

Comment: Thanks ; because the first form prepare the date for the second form. Second form force date with the first date, because the second form have others elements with between the date. :-S

Comment: Je viens de voir que tu étais français :) En fait, j'ai un formulaire avec simplement une date, lorsqu'on le valide, je souhaiterais que cela redirige vers un second formulaire qui reprend cette date et la force (avec les arguments years / monh / year). Tout cela fonctionne, seul le controller me pose problème. Le but de tout ça c'est que, dans le second formulaire, je limite d'autres données (provenant de la base de données) grâce à la date entrée dans le premier formulaire. :)

Comment: Alors si tes deux formulaire sont complètement distincts pourquoi ne pas faire deux actions ?

Un première qui affiche le premier formulaire et le valide, puis créer second formulaire qui sera validé par une autre action

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a flow from FormType with this bundle: [CraueFormFlowBundle](https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle)